# Autoupdate database structure (without data)

Tags: c#, wpf

Im wonder, if its possible to compare somehow two database (ill write example, but not sure if its works like that):

I have 2 Pc's. They have the same instance and DB name, but another structure - in DB_PC1 im working all the time, updating, changing, deleting, inserting etc. Now, in the end of day I want the same database in DB_PC2. Of course i can script all tables as *.sql, but is it possible to create (for example) backup of my DB_PC1 and somehow compare it in DB_PC2 with auto-accept changes ?

I also know that i can use restore database, but i dont want to change any data in DB_PC2.
Maybe someone have c# example that can do it?

Comment: It's more of a task related to database replication than writing code, [here is the SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of SQL Server Replication, if you want it to be done at Server level. If you need Accept Changes kinda stuff, you can do it using tools like SQL COmparer. There are lot of tools available. Just google it.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Comment: I dont want to use commercial solutions. I've used before sqlcompare from mssql, but that accept changes for structure and data.

Comment: By sqlcompare i mean tablediff. actually its great, but why i just cant compare schema, not data ;(

Comment: You can still do it with sql Compare. If you want free tools, that are also available, Google it with DB Schema COmpare. you will find it.

Comment: Well yes, i know i can find lot of tools, but Im writing commercial application, and i want to use sonething like auto-update database. So problem is that i'd like to build it inside application, without using another tool. Not sure if it's still possible, but google is my friend so maybe someday ill find sonething;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Roundhouse](http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/) project. It works like version control system for db.